# react-native app crashes while I want to run debugger-ui react-native-debbugger

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npm-install, react-native-debugger

I have started my application and install `npm packages` using `npm install`, then as usual I have installed debug version of the application using `npx react-native run-android`, then started the application with `npx react-native start`. The works fine until I want to use debugger-ui and debug my application using `react-native-debugger` or `fb-flipper`.
The problem occurs when pressing `r` in the terminal and choosing `Debug` from the modal that appears on the emulator screen.
This is the error that I'm facing with int he terminal:
[image]

And also this one in the `React Native Debugger` tab in the chrome console:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm using the latest version of `react-native-reanimated` in this project and have followed the installation instructions in the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation) I have used this command for installing that:

```sh
npm install react-native-reanimated@next
```

I have been looking into documentation and after reading that really carefully I have just figured out that the `react-native-reanimated@2` is not going to work with `react-native-debugger` and you can run `debugger-ui` the documentation recommended to use [facebook flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) another amazing developer tool for react-native apps.